# I need to trace my kernel in FreeBSD, It is getting stuck at bootup because I'm changing the scheduler, How do I do that?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, kernel, scheduling, freebsd

I am modifying my scheduler and it's causing it to get stuck (because I'm not able to implement it properly, and I'm not picking up stuff I throw in the queues). So i'm trying to see how far it gets. How do I write stuff into a log, and then how do I read that log, when I boot up kernel.old

I am throwing my threads into a new set of queues, instead of the traditional 3 runq's of 64 each. To traverse and pick a thread, I'm using TAILQ_FOREACH.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong.

What you should do is run this is a hypervisor with support for debuggers, like qemu or bhyve. Then you attach gdb to the kernel you boot and inspect the state as it crashes.

In principle you /could/ have a log you write stuff to and which you retrieve after a failed boot, but I don't see why would you do this. The simplest way of achieving this would be to simply printf and possibly extend the size of the buffer so that you can fit more messages. The kernel always puts the log at the same location and checks a magic number on boot so that it knows whether it should start from scratch or start appending. Then said log is available in dmesg and /var/log/messages. But as noted earlier, **that's not the way to do it**.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to break into the debugger? https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/kerneldebug-online-ddb.html

DTrace might also be useful.